# SSIS: Catch Invalid Zip files

Tags: ssis, zip, 7zip

I am extracting zip files using 7zip in SSIS. Problem is that the source might contain invalid zip files. Is there a way to catch invalid zip files in SSIS so it will skip the file and process with the next?

Comment: Are you using a Script Task to extract the zip files?

Comment: no, an execute process task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an error handler that does not propagate its error to its parent container.

This article is an excellent guide on how to implement:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rushabh_mehta/archive/2008/04/24/gracefully-handing-task-error-in-ssis-package.aspx

Specifically, what it explains is how to put your Execute Process Task inside a Sequence Container, and set the error handling on the Sequence Container such that any errors that occur there do not raise an error in your foreach or for loop.

Comment: I have done this, but the problem is that it will skipp all other files that needs to be extracted and those files are valid.

Comment: It will not skip all other files -- that's the point of setting the propagate property to false.  In a foreach, if an error is encountered on one zip file, then the package will raise an error but then also still move on to the next zip file.